# Reference a symbol in a Go package without knowing if you are in that package?

Tags: go, name-lookup

Assume there is a function `F` in package `A` that some code I'm creating needs to call. How do I call it?

If I'm Calling it from outside package `A`, then I uses `A.F(...)` and if I'm inside `A` I uses `F(...)`. But what if Murphy prevents me from knowing which is true or requires a byte identical line work in both?

[note: I'm taking it as a given that such a case will occur because, in my experience and observations, that is generally a safe assumption. Even in the absence of technical reasons for it, [PHB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss)s and legislators are good sources of the ridiculous.]

Comment: Can't you just always use `A.F()` in the Go language? Why wouldn't you know this at compile time?

Comment: Can't. Go users seem to get by anyway, somehow. :)

Comment: `A.F` from inside `A` refers to `A.A.F` which doesn't exist. -- I'm asking this mostly out of curiosity about if Go includes an escape hatch for this or if it assume the world will always match it's expectations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "the fundamental perversity of the universe."

Answer (score 3):

There is no such syntax. Observe the following things:

- Cyclical imports are forbidden. This especially means that a package cannot import itself. Thus, a package cannot refer to one of its symbols `S` with the `pkg.S` syntax because it will not be able to import itself.
- Even if you solved that problem, observe  that packages can be given an arbitrary name once imported. For instance, you could do:

  ```
  import bar "foo"
  ```

  Which imports `S` from package `"foo"` as `bar.S` as opposed to the expected `foo.S`.

The following things could be used to work around this:

- In the package `"foo"`, create an internal object `foo` whose members are the symbols `foo` exports. This allows you to use the `foo.S` syntax in `foo` itself, but is a horrible kludge.
- Use an import declaration like

  ```
  import . "foo"
  ```

  which allows you to use symbol `S` from package `"foo"` as `S`, i. e. without prefix. Notice that this kind of import declaration, called *dot imports*, is considered bad style and might break things if the set of symbols you declare / the package you import declares changes.

Comment: Yuck. Why doesn't it just have a FQN anchor (e.g. prefix `::` in C++)

Comment: @BCS Why should it? This is only needed in C++ because C++ allows arbitrary things with name-spaces. In Go, the name-space inside a file never changes so why should there be such a syntax? There is also no preprocessor, so even less reason.

Comment: In the *rare* case that I only need to worry about technical constraints, you are probably correct. But in the general case...

Comment: @BCS In what *general* case? I don't understand your question.

Comment: In the general case, thing are more constrained by laws, money and PHBs than what the programming language allows.

Comment: If you have a PHB who sets forth useless programming standards, I feel bad for you. Maybe you can get him to improve the standards if they are not applicable to this language?

Comment: I'm not saying I am working under the exact constraints I mentioned, but that non-technical constraints are *normal* (and all to often can be far from useless). Saying there is no "technical" reason that I would even need to do something in my code is like saying a "good driver" has no reason to wear a seat-belt.

Comment: @BCS The technical reasons for that kind of convention stem from the fact that you can change between name-spaces at will in C++ and some other languages. Thus it makes sense to require fully-qualified names because you can't reliably know about the namespace you are in. The namespacing model of Go is different and most importantly the namespace does not change in one source file. It is thus very easy to know the namespace a symbol comes from, compared to C++. Of course, you should avoid `import . "some/package"` if you care about this kind of things, but fully qualified names aren't needed.